# How to manage width of bootstrap columns without changing the bootstrap.css file?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to place my elements inside a bootstrap row (inside columns) to fit my needs, however, I faced with problems. The column width is 97px approx. for large screens. 
What should I do, to place inside such a column a control element (date picker or button) that oversizes the column width? The only options is to override standard bootstrap styles (generate new css) or merge several columns? What other options do I have?

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <input type="checkbox" /> /* How han I change the margine between elements?*/
            <div class="arrow-down">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!--- Date Time Picker control-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-time">7 h 49 min</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn-block">Add work time</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn-block">Add break</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may add styles within `<style>` in the header section of your html, after the link to the bootstrap css, or use inline styles.

Comment: Actually I have my own custom.css where I add required styles. But I am on the UI prototyping stage and one of the requirements is add the custom css as least as possible. Another requirement is not to change bootstrap styles at all